# Input text fields aren't clickable at certain browser size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been messing around with bootstrap just for a few weeks now trying to get used to the grid and stuff so I'm not sure what's going on here or if it's even with me messing up some code in the html. I even commented out my custom css style sheet for that page and for some reason I can't click on any of the text fields in my form at a browser size. It seems to happen from 768px-1199px browser size. I have this problem when I have the classes col-lg-6 col-sm-12 on my div tag.

When I put those classes on the input tag the fields reach 100% andI can click on the text fields, but I can't get it to look like the design where it's supposed to be three text fields to the left and 3 fields to the right.

Here is my HTML and custom CSS. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Theory/pen/YWjYoZ)

```
<form id="ad-form">
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">Wickliffe Italian-American Club</h1>
    <h4 class="text-center">2016 Pat O'brien Chevrolet Cleveland Challenge Cup of Bocce Advertisement Form</h4>
    <p class="bg-danger text-center">Paragraph</p>

 <!-- BEGIN TEXT INPUT FORM -->
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <label for="company"><h5>Company</h5></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <label for="fl-name"><h5>Contact Name</h5></label>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="fl-name" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <label for="address"><h5>Address</h5></label>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address, City, State, Zip" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <label for="phone"><h5>Phone Number</h5></label> 
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Contact Phone Number" />
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <label for="email"><h5>Email</h5></label>
    <input type="email" required class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
  </div>    
  <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
    <label for="reference"><h5>Referred by Italian-American Club Member</h5></label>
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="reference" placeholder="Reference Name" />
  </div>
  <!-- END TEXT INPUT FORM -->

  <!-- BEGIN RADIO FORM -->  
   <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
     <h5>Please select appropriate ad size below:</h5>
     <div class="radio">
     <label>
         <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1">
         Full Page (4.5in x 7.5in) - <strong>$125.00</strong>
     </label>
     </div>
     <div class="radio">
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2">
         1/2 Page (4.5in x 3.75in) - <strong>$75</strong>
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="radio">
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3">
         1/4 Page (4.5in x 1.875in) - <strong>$35.00</strong>
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="radio">
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4">
         Patron Ad - <strong>$15.00</strong>
       </label>
       <div>
           <input type="submit" />
       </div>
     </div> 
   </div><!-- END RADIO FORM -->
</div><!-------- END CONTAINER -------->
```

CSS

```
#ad-form {
margin-top: 100px;   
}

#ad-form p {
margin: 30px 0px;
}

#ad-form h5 {
font-weight:  bolder;
color: #158000;
}

.bg-danger {
color: #730000;
border: 1px solid #d4b7b7;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 15px;
font-style: italic;
}

.form-group {
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.form-control:focus   {
border-color: #9ac19d;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(175, 211, 178, .6);
}

.form-control {
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #9ac19d;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue caused by **floating** which you can resolve in several ways: you can wrap your columns in rows, clear the `float` with CSS yourself or separate your form-group & column class into individual `div`s.

***Note:** Keep in mind that you're directly altering some class rules so you will want use either a new class or specificity as to not change these rules globally otherwise you `may` have issues in other areas of your application when using these same classes again.

**Working Examples:**

**Example adding `row`s**

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #ad-form {
    background: lightblue;
  }
}
#ad-form {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#ad-form p {
  margin: 30px 0px;
}
#ad-form h5 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #158000;
}
#ad-form .bg-danger {
  color: #730000;
  border: 1px solid #d4b7b7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}
#ad-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#ad-form .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #9ac19d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(175, 211, 178, .6);
}
#ad-form .form-control {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #9ac19d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="ad-form">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1 class="text-center">Wickliffe Italian-American Club</h1>
        <h4 class="text-center">Tournament Name</h4>
        <p class="bg-danger text-center">Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <label for="company">
          <h5>Company</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company Name" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <label for="fl-name">
          <h5>Contact Name</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="fl-name" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <label for="address">
          <h5>Address</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address, City, State, Zip" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <label for="phone">
          <h5>Phone Number</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Contact Phone Number" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <label for="email">
          <h5>Email</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="email" required class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <label for="reference">
          <h5>Referred by Italian-American Club Member</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="reference" placeholder="Reference Name" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
        <h5>Please select appropriate ad size below:</h5>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1"><strong>$125.00</strong>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2"><strong>$75</strong>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3"><strong>$35.00</strong>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4"> <strong>$15.00</strong>
          </label>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

**Example Clearing Floats:**

*Example CSS*

```
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1199px) {
  #ad-form .form-group {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #ad-form {
    background: lightblue;
  }
  #ad-form .form-group {
    clear: left;
  }
}
#ad-form {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#ad-form p {
  margin: 30px 0px;
}
#ad-form h5 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #158000;
}
#ad-form .bg-danger {
  color: #730000;
  border: 1px solid #d4b7b7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}
#ad-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#ad-form .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #9ac19d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(175, 211, 178, .6);
}
#ad-form .form-control {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #9ac19d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="ad-form">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="text-center">Wickliffe Italian-American Club</h1>
      <h4 class="text-center">Tournament Name</h4>
      <p class="bg-danger text-center">Paragraph</p>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="company">
        <h5>Company</h5>
      </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company Name" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="fl-name">
        <h5>Contact Name</h5>
      </label>
      <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="fl-name" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="address">
        <h5>Address</h5>
      </label>
      <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address, City, State, Zip" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="phone">
        <h5>Phone Number</h5>
      </label>
      <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Contact Phone Number" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="email">
        <h5>Email</h5>
      </label>
      <input type="email" required class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <label for="reference">
        <h5>Referred by Italian-American Club Member</h5>
      </label>
      <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="reference" placeholder="Reference Name" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
      <h5>Please select appropriate ad size below:</h5>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1"><strong>$125.00</strong>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2"><strong>$75</strong>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3"><strong>$35.00</strong>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="radio">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4"> <strong>$15.00</strong>
        </label>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

**Example with Columns and Form-Group Separated:**

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #ad-form {
    background: lightblue;
  }
}
#ad-form {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
#ad-form p {
  margin: 30px 0px;
}
#ad-form h5 {
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #158000;
}
#ad-form .bg-danger {
  color: #730000;
  border: 1px solid #d4b7b7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-style: italic;
}
#ad-form .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#ad-form .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #9ac19d;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(175, 211, 178, .6);
}
#ad-form .form-control {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #9ac19d;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="ad-form">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h1 class="text-center">Wickliffe Italian-American Club</h1>
        <h4 class="text-center">2016 Pat O'brien Chevrolet Cleveland Challenge Cup of Bocce Advertisement Form</h4>
        <p class="bg-danger text-center">Paragraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">
          <h5>Company</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company Name" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fl-name">
          <h5>Contact Name</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="fl-name" placeholder="First and Last Name" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">
          <h5>Address</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address, City, State, Zip" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">
          <h5>Phone Number</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Contact Phone Number" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">
          <h5>Email</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="email" required class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reference">
          <h5>Referred by Italian-American Club Member</h5>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="reference" placeholder="Reference Name" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <h5>Please select appropriate ad size below:</h5>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1"><strong>$125.00</strong>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="option2"><strong>$75</strong>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios3" value="option3"><strong>$35.00</strong>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios4" value="option4"> <strong>$15.00</strong>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked! I just had to add that clear in there. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem and glad it world for you.